# Flutter ListView condition only Displays the first item in a list

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am quite new to Flutter and Dart development.
I am trying to display a list of all of the items in a JSON List that match a particular criteria, with the criteria being a type of alcohol in this case. I have created an IF statement at the top of what the ListBuilder returns, but it only returns the first item in the list when it matches the criteria. For example, I have three objects where the category is "Rum", but it still only returns the first one. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
    class CocktailCategoryList extends StatefulWidget {
 
  @override
  _CocktailListState createState() => _CocktailListState();
}

class _CocktailListState extends State<CocktailCategoryList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        height: 55,
        width: 55,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(86, 99, 255, 100),
              onPressed: () {
                
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.shuffle,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 35,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation:
          FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniCenterDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 20,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 55,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.list,
                  color: Colors.purple[700],
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28),
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "Cocktails",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var cocktailData = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cocktailData == null ? 0 : cocktailData.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
               if (cocktailData[index]['category'] == "Rum"){ 
                  Column(
                  children: [
                    SafeArea(
                      minimum: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 0, 15, 0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => CocktailPage(
                                      cocktailData[index]['name'],
                                      cocktailData[index]['subtitle'],
                                      cocktailData[index]['category'],
                                      cocktailData[index]['instructions'],
                                      cocktailData[index]['image'],
                                      cocktailData[index]['ingredients'],
                                    ))),
                        child: Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: Wrap(children: [
                            Image(
                              image: NetworkImage(cocktailData[index]['image']),
                            ),
                          ]),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => CocktailPage(
                                    cocktailData[index]['name'],
                                    cocktailData[index]['subtitle'],
                                    cocktailData[index]['category'],
                                    cocktailData[index]['instructions'],
                                    cocktailData[index]['image'],
                                    cocktailData[index]['ingredients'],
                                  ))),
                      child: ListTile(
                        visualDensity:
                            VisualDensity(horizontal: 0, vertical: -1),
                        title: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              cocktailData[index]['name'],
                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            CategoryTag(
                                cocktailData[index]['category']) //Button Here
                          ],
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(cocktailData[index]['subtitle']),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10)
                  ],
                );
                }else {
                  SizedBox();
                }
                
              }
            );
          },
          future:
              DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/testJson.json'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that you are not returning the `Column` widget in your `ListView.builder()` inside of the if statement. The anonymous builder function that you provide to the `ListView.builder()` should always return a widget.